# Why does memset fail and calloc succeed?

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, calloc

I'm trying to initialise an array of 26 strings. I'd prefer not to place the array on the heap, but I get a segmentation fault when I try to assign memory to the array using `memset`. The code to reproduce this is below:

```
char *string_array[26];
for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++)
    memset(string_array[x], 0, 3 + x); //= calloc(3+x, sizeof(char));
```

If I change the code so that memory is assigned to the heap, with `calloc`, I don't get a segmentation fault:

```
char *string_array[26];
for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++)
    string_array[x] = calloc(3 + x, sizeof(char));
```

Why is that?

Comment: There may be a misunderstanding about what [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) does.

Comment: Tip: `sizeof(char)` is `1`, by definition

Comment: @ikegami I read elsewhere that writing `sizeof(char)` was used for clarity. Was that bad advice?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether you think it's an array of bytes or array of glyphs. `1` would be clearer for the former, but I guess that `sizeof(char)` might be clearer for the latter.

Comment: To add to what @ikegami correctly pointed out about `sizeof(char)`: Using `sizeof(type)` in allocations is often a mistake. For clarity, use the `sizeof <expression>` form. Example: `foo *myfoos = malloc(the_number_of_foos_I_want * sizeof *myfoos);` - `sizeof *myfoos` is an expression that results in the size of a `foo` which ties directly to the variable you're declaring. It's much harder to make mistakes using the expression form (my opinion).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Okay, so I would use `sizeof char` instead?

Comment: @Connor No, that's not an expression. `char` is a _type_ so that wouldn't compile (or do anything for clarity).  The point is to allocate memory with the proper size for the pointer you declare, so you _dereference_ the pointer in the `sizeof` expression (which does _not_ evaluate the dereferenced pointer). `int *arr = malloc(10 * sizeof *arr);` makes an array of 10 `int` - and the connection between the declared pointer and the expression is clear.

Comment: Compare with `int *arr = malloc(10 * sizeof(long));` - this code will work and most probably overallocate memory for generations, just because someone changed one of the two _types_ mentioned. `int` and `long`. If you declare something, it's practical to use that declaration in the allocating expression. There will be fewer mistakes when maintenance has to be done.

Comment: @Connor Just between the two of us (schh), I was 40+ when I realized that there was a even a difference between `sizeof(type)` and `sizeof expression`. Nowadays I omit parentheses to emphasize the expression form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the snippet using `calloc`, you create 27 arrays: one array of pointers in automatic storage<sup>[1]</sup>, and 26 arrays of chars on the heap.

In the snippet using `memset`, you create the array of pointers, and that's it. You attempt to modify 26 arrays of chars, but you never created them.

The following would be equivalent to the calloc snippet, but using only automatic storage.

```c
char string00[  3 ] = { 0 };
char string01[  4 ] = { 0 };
char string02[  5 ] = { 0 };
char string03[  6 ] = { 0 };
char string04[  7 ] = { 0 };
char string05[  8 ] = { 0 };
char string06[  9 ] = { 0 };
char string07[ 10 ] = { 0 };
char string08[ 11 ] = { 0 };
char string09[ 12 ] = { 0 };
char string10[ 13 ] = { 0 };
char string11[ 14 ] = { 0 };
char string12[ 15 ] = { 0 };
char string13[ 16 ] = { 0 };
char string14[ 17 ] = { 0 };
char string15[ 18 ] = { 0 };
char string16[ 19 ] = { 0 };
char string17[ 20 ] = { 0 };
char string18[ 21 ] = { 0 };
char string19[ 22 ] = { 0 };
char string20[ 23 ] = { 0 };
char string21[ 24 ] = { 0 };
char string22[ 25 ] = { 0 };
char string23[ 26 ] = { 0 };
char string24[ 27 ] = { 0 };
char string25[ 28 ] = { 0 };
char *string_array[ 26 ] = {
   string00, string01, string02, string03, string04,
   string05, string06, string07, string08, string09,
   string10, string11, string12, string13, string14,
   string15, string16, string17, string18, string19,
   string20, string21, string22, string23, string24,
   string25,
};
```

Now, if we assume there's no alignment restriction for `char`, we could simplify the above as follows:

```c
char buffer[ 403 ] = { 0 };  // 3+4+5+...+28 = 403
char *string_array[ 26 ];
for ( size_t j=0, i=0; j<26; ++j ) {
   string_array[ j ] = buffer + i;
   i += j + 3;
}
```

Finally, as @Ted Lyngmo points out, some compilers provide `alloca`/`_alloca` to allocate in automatic storage.

```c
char *string_array[ 26 ];
for ( size_t j=0; j<26; ++j ) {
   string_array[ j ] = alloca( j + 3 );       // This is what you were missing.
   memset( string_array[ j ], 0, j + 3 );
}
```

---

C doesn't have a concept of stack and heap. The C standard doesn't mandate where the objects are stored, only the duration for which they can be accessed. This is called *storage duration*.

So the following isn't based on the standard, but is nearly universally true:

| objects with automatic storage duration | objects with allocated storage duration |
| --- | --- |
| On the stack, in a register, or optimized away | On the heap |
| Needs less time/CPU to allocate | Needs more time/CPU to allocate |
| Needs less space/memory to allocate | Needs more space/memory to allocate |
| Limited control over lifespan of the allocated block | Lifespan can extend beyond the function that allocated the memory |
| Uncatchable dire consequences to over-allocating | Over-allocating can be detected and handled |
| Somewhat limited resource | Vast resource |
| Always available | Not available on some systems (e.g. many embedded systems) |
| Can be hard/impossible to allocate complex structures unless the compiler provides non-standard `alloca` or similar. | Simple to allocate complex structures |

There are two storage durations not covered here: static and thread.

---

1. There's no guarantee that a stack is used. But yeah, it's probably going to be a stack.

Comment: Am I tying myself in knots and overthinking the stack and the heap? Is it actually possible to completely control where memory is stored in C? Is it even significantly faster to work off the stack?

Comment: What have you done with the buffer in the second code snippet? How does that let me allocate string arrays of variable length?

Comment: C doesn't guarantee a stack. And it might not even use memory for variables. It could use registers or optimize their need away completely. /// C doesn't guarantee a heap. In particular, you can't malloc on many embedded systems. /// So no, you can't completely control where something is stored.

Comment: In that case, should I just use what works and let the compiler do the rest for me? Is there ever a time when using `calloc` and `malloc` is a bad idea when it comes to dynamically assigned arrays of arrays?

Comment: @Connor Memory is just one huge block of bytes we subdivide for use for different things. And that's exactly what I do with the buffer. The various pointers in `string_array` point to different areas of `buffer`.

Comment: There are various factors that can affect whether you want to use automatic storage or not. But unless there's a problem, don't worry about it. Use whatever's easier/clearer.

Comment: Added a table to my answer about automatic vs [cm]alloc

Comment: Can't update the answer myself because the queue is too long. But I think removing "duration" from the table headers would make more sense, it makes the first row very confusing. What is a "slower" duration?

Comment: *Am I tying myself in knots and overthinking the stack and the heap?* Quite possibly. :-)  Dynamically-allocated ("heap") memory is ever-so-slightly more expensive, and somewhat of a nuisance, but it is not something you want to generally avoid.  *If* you've got a simple, fixed-size array, then using an ordinary array (or a VLA) can be a fine simplification.  But I don't think of strings as being amenable to "simple, fixed-size arrays".  In general, you never know how long a string is going to be, so you just about always want to malloc (or strdup) the right amount of space for it on the heap.

Comment: Tweaked wording.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>I'm assuming OPs implementation actually has a heap and a stack</sup>

> Is it possible to dynamically assign these pointers on the stack?

The ***pointers*** are already on the stack. If you are asking about the memory your pointers are pointing at, then yes. C has Variable Length Arrays (VLAs for short) - but then you have a problem with scope. An automatic variable (such as a VLA) is destroyed at the end of the scope in which it's declared.

```c
for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
    char myvla[3 + x];          // assuming a stack exists, that's where this goes
                                // use myvla as you please here.
}                               // <- and here it goes away
```

If you want dynamically allocated memory on the stack to stick beyond the immediate scope and last until the function returns, you can probably (!) use  `alloca`/`_alloca`. It's a non-standard function that does dynamic memory allocation on the stack.

It usually comes in one of these forms:

```
void *alloca(size_t size);
void *_alloca(size_t size);
```

Example:

```c
#include <alloca.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *string_array[26];

    for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
        string_array[x] = alloca(3 + x); // stack allocation
    }

    // use afterwards
    for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
        memset(string_array[x], 0, 3 + x);
    }
} // here the stack allocated memory is freed - do not use after this
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that if I try and create VLAs in a for loop the memory will be freed as soon as the for loop exits?

Comment: @Connor VLAs will be freed at the end of the **immediate** scope in which they are declared so each VLA lives in _one_ iteration of the loop above - not until the loop ends. `alloca`d objects, no, they live until the function returns, which is why they solve the scoping issue to a degree.

Comment: So you can't dynamically assign stack-based arrays without `alloca`?

Comment: @Connor Yes, with VLAs - but, then you have the scope issue - which doesn't have to actually be an issue. If you pass the stack allocated array to a function that uses it within the loop, no problem.

Comment: So if I pass the array's reference to a function that forces the memory to live when it's returned to the calling block?

Comment: @Connor No, passing it to a function doesn't actually do anything to extend the life of the stack allocated memory. It's just that, while the memory _is_ allocated (that is, in the scope), you can pass pointers to it around just like pointers to any other memory.

Answer (score 2):

`char *string_array[26];` only allocates an array of pointers on the stack.

Using memset to then initialize what the pointers are pointing to is undefined behavior because that memory is not allocated yet.

Comment: The C standard doesn't require the use of a *stack*.

Comment: @Haris No, but since OP _"prefer not to place the array on the heap"_ I think it's safe to assume that OPs implementation uses one.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *string_array[26];
```

declares an array[26] of pointers to `char`. Note that this only allocates memory for the pointers, and not the pointed to data.

> The memset() function fills the first n bytes of the memory area
> pointed to by s with the constant byte c.

Your code invokes undefined behaviour because it is writing to memory that doesn't belong to it. The contents of the pointers are indeterminate, i.e. they may be pointing to anything, and it is not legal for the process to access the memory pointed to by the pointers.

`calloc()`, on the other hand, is used for dynamically allocating memory.

> The calloc() function shall allocate unused space for an array of
> nelem elements each of whose size in bytes is elsize.  The space
> shall be initialized to all bits 0.

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically assign these pointers on the stack?

Comment: I believe you're looking for an array or arrays (or 2d arrays, as they are called in other languages). But by dynamic, do you want the pointed-to data to have the same lifetime as the process?

Answer (score 1):

Memset is used to fill a block of memory with a particular value . Generally memset is used to reset the block of memory with default values before reusing the blocks. Memset is not a substitution of memory allocation (i.e calloc and malloc) . That is the reason your first snippet fails due to setting values in unallocated memory range where as the 2nd snippet is actually allocating memory .